# Are there problems with using Ordered Quantile (ORQ) normalization for Multivariate Analysis?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, normalization, normality-assumption, ancova, manova

This is intended as a general question, as a Google search for -- "Ordered Quantile" "ORQ" normalization "Multivariate Analysis" -- returns nothing.

This option is listed as a result of using the bestNormalize package in R.  The ORQ transformation is "semiparametric," and maps the point by quartile based on a normal distribution.

It is appropriate to use this transformation on a continuous dependent variable in multivariate analysis (MA)?  I am specifically interested in factorial ANOVA, Factorial MANOVA, and ANCOVA.

My specific situation is the qqPlot of the dependent variable has some drift starting just before 2 SDs above and below the mean (to about twice as far from the center line as the dotted lines allow - dotted lines from the car package - so not severe).

Other normalization options (bestNormalize) improve the fit on one end or the other.  ORQ produces a passing qqPlot.

The dependent variable is the raw score on a test in a certain class, that directly measures the subject matter of the class.  The class (required) is given to Jr high students in a country in Europe, and the dataset has many related demographic variables.  The sample size in 380 students.

There are many categorical variables in the dataset, and a few continuous ones (hence ANCOVA), and I want to test different combinations of the them to test different hypotheses.

Past experience says normalizing the dependent variable corrects for non-normal residuals with this type of analysis, although I haven't actually seen the residuals yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. I don't have a well-thought-out response, but as the author of the `bestNormalize` package I suggest you use ORQ normalization in this context as a last resort. If you find a separate, non-complicated transformation works as well, I'd go with it. You can investigate the shape of the ORQ transform with `plot`, and perhaps this will guide you to a non-complicated transformation that you can apply in your context (since it seems none of the other default ones work too well).

If you must use ORQ normalization, I would only use a cross-section of the data to train the transformation (i.e. train the transformation using the baseline data values), then use that transformation object and `predict` to apply it to the later data. I say this because I worry that high within-subject correlation might be exacerbated by using bestNormalize on the full vector of correlated data.

Hope this helps,